# What does Gold Lion Shiki say at the beginning of "Strong World: Episode 0"?

Tags: one-piece

At the beginning of the OVA *[One Piece Film Strong World: Episode 0](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Film_Strong_World:_Episode_0)*, Gold Lion Shiki says something to the Straw Hat crews ([YouTube reference](https://youtu.be/WypW_gw9p08?t=35s)), which a certain fansubber refused to translate since they considered it as a spoiler to the related movie [*One Piece Film: Strong World*](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Film:_Strong_World).

What does Gold Lion Shiki say at the beginning of the OVA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no spoilers. Shiki is basically saying Nami cannot save her friends by sacrificing herself.

Also, it was quite easy to find a [YouTube video with English subtitle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlphYS23su0).

Comment: According to the French subtitle on the question, it seems it's a spoiler to the *Strong World* movie, considering this OVA is related to that movie. You might consider updating the answer if you feel like it.